# postgresql query from php - pg_query_params() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

Tags: php, postgresql

PHP Version: 7
Postgres version: 9.6

We are developing a web application that sends a query to a postgres database, and currently I am updating some queries that were vulnerable to sql injection.  However, when using the `pg_query_params` function, I receive the error

`pg_query_params() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`

This would refer to the 2nd parameter, right? But it is definitely not null, it is a string representing the sql query.  This is our php code (I am aware the `$FeatureCollection` is still being concatenated and therefore SQL-injection vulnerble, but there are more steps involved in fixing this one):

```
$conn = dbconn();

$from = $_POST['from']; //node id of the 'from' location, passed from ajax
$to = $_POST['to']; //node id of the 'to' location, passed from ajax

$sql = 'SELECT json_build_object(
        \'type\',       \'FeatureCollection\',
        \'features\',   jsonb_agg(feature)
    )
    FROM (
        SELECT json_build_object(
            \'type\',       \'Feature\',
            \'id\',         edge,
            \'geometry\',   ST_AsGeoJSON(the_geom)::json,
            \'properties\', to_jsonb(row) - \'id\' - \'geom\'
    ) AS
        feature
    FROM
        (
            SELECT * FROM pgr_nogo_dijkstra(
                    \'SELECT gid AS id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost, the_geom AS geom FROM ways\',
                    (
                        SELECT
                            ST_SetSRID(ST_Union(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(feat->>\'geometry\')), 4326)
                        FROM (
                            SELECT json_array_elements(
                                \'{
                                    "type": "FeatureCollection",
                                    "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
                                    "features":
                                        ['.$FeatureCollection.'] // still vulnerable, will be fixed later
                                }\'
                                ::json->\'features\'
                            ) AS
                                feat
                        ) AS
                            f
                    ),
                    $1,
                    $2,
                    TRUE
                ) AS route_result
            INNER JOIN
                ways
            ON
                ways.gid = route_result.edge
        )
    row) features;
    ';

result = pg_query_params( $conn, $sql, array($from, $to) ) or die('Query Failed: ' .pg_last_error());
```

`$sql` definitely is not null, it is defined right beforehand.  THe query was working beforehand, when we were just using string concatenation and `pg_query()`, so I'm not sure what is so different that is making `pg_query_params()` fail.

EDIT: I Should also not that `dbconn()` refers to another function that is imported from another php file:

```
function dbconn(){

        ini_set('display_errors', 1); // Dispalys errors
        // fetch config params
        $config = file_get_contents('../config.json');
        $json = json_decode($config, true);
        //echo $json['db_host'];


        //database login info
        $host = $json['db_host'];
        $port = $json['db_port'];
        $dbname = $json['db_name'];
        $user = $json['db_user'];
        $password = $json['db_pwd'];
        // establish connection         
        $conn = pg_connect("host=$host port=$port dbname=$dbname user=$user password=$password");
        if (!$conn) {
            echo "Not connected : " . pg_error();
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _“his would refer to the 2nd parameter, right?”_ - no, it refers to the first. (This is “natural-language counting”, not “programmer counting”.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so: no parameter 1 isn't the second parameter its the first one.
your dbconn function is not returning the connection.

add a

```
return $conn;
```

at the end of your dbconn function and you should be fine.

Comment: This works, but now the query is not recognizing the parameters as being integers, postgres is interpreting them as "unknown": `Query Failed: ERROR:  function pgr_nogo_dijkstra(unknown, geometry, unknown, unknown, boolean) is not unique`.  How can I force them to be passed as integers?

Comment: Try checking if the post data is there. I would do:

_if(issset($_POST['from']))
   $from = $_POST['from'];
else //error handling_

also try to work timesave with your paramethers. your post values will allways be string. you can give the params a typ like this:

_$1::numeric_

Comment: But my guess is that your javascript is posting "unknown" to your webserver. mostly if javascript is not able to find variables it returns "unknown" as value. Don't forgett javascript is casesensitive.